# Tags function in jQuery not working even after adding jQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add tabs to my website to navigate b/w two sub-menus.  Essentially when you click 'Highlight' or 'News' a new set of elements appear in that section.

I added the jquery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but still when I check the console I get the message "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object has no method 'tabs'"is not defined.

I added the library:

```
<script src="public/scripts/applicat.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

but when I check the console for '$("body") and it returns a 'null'. (The uploaded file on the website has this applicat.js file included)

I have tried everything but can't seem to figure out how to add the tabs method and also not have a problem with the jQuery linking to my HTML.

This is how the tabs function is called (right before the end of body):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery().ready(function() { 
jQuery("#discussion-sections > nav ul").tabs("#discussion-sections > section");
});
</script>
```

// Bonus question
Do you have any idea how I can expand the length of the tabs header so that the horizontal line goes across the page?  I tried adding a border-bottom to the UL where the tabs are defined but in this case it adds a line even to the area underneath the selected tab.

Thanks,
Luis

Comment: Please add your js code in your question.

Comment: put ur code that is accessing jquery functions inside document.ready method. also for testing, why dont you download the jquery library and use it locally in your solution instead of referring externally.

Comment: @Pawan, Thanks, I added the library locally now. I thought I was calling the function inside the document.ready.

Comment: @Hailwood - call to method added.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this `http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js` and it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object has no method 'tabs'"is not defined.:-

The library is not called properly.please call the tab mathod inside the document.ready function

Comment: I thought I was... this is how I was calling it: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery().ready(function() { 
     jQuery("#discussion-sections > nav ul").tabs("#discussion-sections > section");
    });
   </script>`

Comment: Hey Sandeep, could you explain what you mean by placing the tab method within the .ready function?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script src="public/scripts/applicat.js" type="text/javascript">
```

to

```
<script src="public/scripts/applicat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, had forgotten to copy that, I did have the closing tag included. Thanks for pointing it out.